# Proving a recursion relation for a sequence of integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

For  $\large I_n=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{2n+1}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$

I would like to demonstrate  that :

> $\large \forall n\in \mathbb{N}^*,  (2n+1)I_n=\sqrt{2} -2nI_{n-1}$

I tried many combinations including polar coordinates change, in vain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\large \forall n\in \mathbb{N}^*,  (2n+2)I_n +2nI_{n-1}=\int_0^1 \frac{(2n+2)x^{2n+1}+2nx^{2n-1}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx $

$\large \forall n\in \mathbb{N}^*,  (2n+2)I_n +2nI_{n-1}=[\frac{x^{2n+2}+x^{2n}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}]_0^{1}-\int_0^1 \frac{x^{2n+3}+x^{2n+1}}{-\sqrt{1+x^2}^3}dx $

$\large \forall n\in \mathbb{N}^*,  (2n+2)I_n +2nI_{n-1}=\sqrt2+\int_0^1 \frac{x^{2n+1}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx = \sqrt2+ I_n $

$\large \forall n\in \mathbb{N}^*,  (2n+2)I_n +2nI_{n-1}= \sqrt2+ I_n  $

Which means

$\large \forall n\in \mathbb{N}^*,  (2n+1)I_n = \sqrt2- (2n)I_{n-1} $

Comment: Assez astucieux come solution . Thanks

Comment: De rien mon ami

Answer (score 3):

**Sketch**:

Using integration by parts with
$$u=x^{2n},\;\mathrm dv=\frac x{\sqrt{1+x^2}},\enspace\text{whence }\enspace \mathrm d u=2nx^{2n-1}\mathrm d x,\; v=\sqrt{1+x^2},$$
 we obtain
\begin{align}
I_n&=x^{2n}\sqrt{1+x^2}\biggr|_0^1-2n\int x^{2n-1}\frac{1+x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\,\mathrm d x \\
&=\sqrt 2 -2n\int \frac{x^{2n-1}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\,\mathrm d x-2n I_n.
\end{align}

Comment: beautiful shortcut. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your kind appreciation.

Comment: @MohammedM.Zerrak: You posted a correction just when  I found the simplification error after integration by parts.

Comment: I really Appreciate both of your replies. Something was missing @ first  but I got the idea. This helped me a lot.